# Angular add a random JPG image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have created an Angular app that has a button which adds a new item to the list, here is a picture of it:

### [image: Angular App]

I searched for sites that provide random images and found "picsum.photos" (Lorem Picsum), which upon refresh indeed gives me a random picture each time.

I've tried implementing this in the code, but I'm getting the same image every time.

TypeScript Code:

```
imgUrl = 'https://some_long_path.jpeg';
randomImgUrl = 'https://picsum.photos/536/354';

recipes1: Recipes[] = [
    new Recipes('A Test Recipe',
      'This is simply a test', this.imgUrl)
];

addRecipe() {
   this.recipes1.push(new Recipes('name', 'description', this.randomImgUrl));
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addRecipe()" (keyup.d)="removeRecipe()">New Recipe</button>
```

It seems only one random image link gets saved into the variable 'randomImgUrl'...

Does anyone know what is the issue? How can I get a random image each time I call the addRecipe() function?

Thank you!

Comment: Adding a parameter to change the url `https://picsum.photos/536/354?t=123`. Ex: replace 123 with the current timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getRandomImgUrl() {
  return this.randomImgUrl + '?cache=' + new Date().getTime()
}

addRecipe() {
  this.recipes1.push(new Recipes('name', 'description', this.getRandomImgUrl()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use random number in randomImgUrl

```
addRecipe() {
this.randomImgUrl=`https://i.picsum.photos/id/${Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)}/535/535.jpg`;
   this.recipes1.push(new Recipes('name', 'description', this.randomImgUrl));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add random queryparam to prevent your browser from caching this image.

```
addRecipe() {
  this.recipes1.push(new Recipes('name', 'description', this.randomImgUrl + '?q=' + Math.random()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change image by appending a cache-busting query string to the end

```
randomImgUrl = 'https://picsum.photos/536/354?a';
```

Comment: The query parameter needs to be randomized somehow or it will just cache that version of the image url.